# Angular http client not working with translation on in IOS chrome browser?

Tags: ios, angular, httpclient, angular-transitions

I have angular project built in angular 10. I am getting issue in calling api from IOS chrome browser when i turn on google translation from browser.

If i do not turn on translation it is giving me correct response for API

However when i turn on translation i am getting this error.

`InvalidAccessError The object does not support the operation or argument`

Error is happening only when i do translation from browser if i do translation from settings in Iphone the it is working fine.

and it is also working fine in all browsers in laptop.

If use javascript `fetch` function instead of angular `HttpClient` then it is working fine with `HttpClient` request is not even going to server. It is giving error even before sending request.

Comment: Can you show us the code that handles the response?

Comment: @NathanToulbert I am using ngx-translate module for translation and that is working with iphone language translation from settings menu. But if i do translation using chrome browser then it is causing error. though i solved it for now by disabling chrome translation.

Comment: Which loader are you using? Consider testing with [this](https://github.com/ngx-translate/http-loader) to see if you get different results.

Comment: I don't think that issue is related to ngx-translate as i created a fresh project without ngx translate and it is having same problem

Comment: Where in the trace is the error?              Then if it is working w/ fetch api, it almost has to be related to httpClient, no?       Combining comments (and deleting old ones) to keep our own stack trace to a minimum.  XD

Comment: almost 3am here. im going to bed. I can hardly think straight. In the morning, after festivities, I will take a fresh look with mind in tact.  In case we do not cross paths again, happy holidays. ----- BTW I plan to clean up my comments litter in the morning.

Comment: @NathanToulbert Yes it is related to httpClient. If you want i will upload my sample project on github and give link here so that you can test on local.

Answer (score 4):

Its because HTTPClient expects a json in response by default and when you turn on translation, its no more a json. Try receiving response like

```
this.http.post(this.url, body, {responseType: 'text'}).subscribe((res)=> console.log(res));
```

also body should be a json like

```
body=JSON.stringify(data);
```

if it prints then if you feel its not a json then map it to javascript object via your code, if it seems a json then use

```
JSON.parse(res);
```

Comment: I tried this but still getting same error though i sovled it by disabling translation option in angular

Comment: I disabled the translation option using these two lines of code
`<html lang="en" translate="no" class="notranslate">`
`<meta name="google" content="notranslate" />`